# Angular UI router 0.2.18 param on root url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an issue where I want to have a parameter on the route url e.g

```
$stateProvider.state('/someRoute', {
    url: '/:path',
    .....
});

$stateProvider.state('/contact', {
    url: '/contact',
    .....
});
```

But if I do that then other pages get misinterpreted as being part of this. for example /contact url thinks that "contact" is the param and not the page.

Is there a way around this or do I need to have a sub-page e.g /something/:path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that currently due to the order of the states, your first state will capture all urls as it's expecting some parameter.

`/contact` satisfies the `/:path` criteria.

Either move the `/:path` as the last state. or create a `/something/:path`

Comment: Much appreciated. Makes sense now.